# javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException - AES/GCM/NoPadding works, then doesn't

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, aes

I am trying to decrypt some data from a DB and have run into some AEADBadTagExceptions, but not always.

While searching for the error, I have taken the cipher initialization and put a loop around the decryption. I.e.

```
GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(authenticationTagLength, ivByte);
cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE_GCM);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
if (additionalDataText.length()>0) {
    cipher.updateAAD(additionalDataText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }                        }
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    cipher.doFinal(cypherBytes);
}
```

Running this code several times, I get 17/500 successes on the first try, then Zero for the next several tries. Changing the code and letting Eclipse rebuild may yield 17 or 18 successes followed by failures.

The exception is as follows

```
[err] javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException
[err]   at com.ibm.crypto.provider.GCTRInHardware.gcm_ad(Unknown Source)
[err]   at com.ibm.crypto.provider.aA.c(Unknown Source)
[err]   at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESGCMCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
[err]   at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESGCMCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
[err]   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
```

Oh yeah, I'm using Java 1.8 on the "IBM J9 VM" if that helps.

Does anyone have any idea what might prompt this behaviour? 
Kind regards

Edit: in additional news, this seems to be caused by something on the server this is running on - I can successfully decrypt the same data on another server, and in a JUnit test. I'll have a look to see if I can find the difference in the configurations.

**Solution** In my jvm.options I had specified a YourKit profiler under the option -agentpath By removing this line from the options, I got it to work.

Comment: You should do updateAAD in the for loop. doFinal reset the cipher in the state after call to init method.

Comment: `.getBytes("UTF-8")` is suspicious. Never use `String` when dealing with binary data. Just use a byte array.

Comment: @rustyx how do you want to do if you need to encrypt a text ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that it was in decrypt mode. I agree with you !

Comment: First of all, thanks for the suggestions. I have moved the updateAAD into the loop, to no avail. I have also switched the additionalBytes to byte[] and transferred them Base64-encoded. This also did not help.

More annoyingly, I've moved the offending code into a JUnit-Test and in there, it runs successfully. So I guess something in my environment is broken, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I didn't know this was going to be relevant: I am running a Websphere Liberty Profile server. As mentioned in my edit, the code works in JUnit and on another server. I've checked the differences and got it to work, so I redid the differences one by one and found it was the following:

In my jvm.options I had specified a YourKit profiler under the option 
    -agentpath
By removing this line from the options, I got it to work.

Not sure what the etiquette is on answering your own questions, so I'll also add this to the question.